# Compile code *For* x86_64 *using* ARM-Cortex-A53(android phone)

Tags: android, gcc, arm, x86-64, cross-compiling

I am well aware that we can compile codes for different devices on x86_64(laptop/PCs) using any of the Cross compiler tool-chain(like for ARM: arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc) but now I am wondering is it possible to compile **for** x86_64 platform **from** ARM(android/cortex-A53). It would be very helpful for me to proceed to a conclusion related to the project.

PS: I am using Linux like command line on android(terminal emulator with root access) for tweaking and running c/c++ code.

Comment: Of course, why not, you can cross compile x86 to x86 arm to x86, arm to mips, mips to arm, etc...Any system that can run the gnu tools can build gnu tools (for the same or any other supported system).

Comment: can you tell the name of the right tool for this for using with termux? A link would be really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to compile for x86_64 from ARM.

If you use GCC, you will have to first build a cross-compilation toolchain. There are some tools which can help generate a cross-compilation toolchain, e.g. Buildroot and crosstool-NG.

On Arch Linux ARM, maybe you can try the prebuilt toolchains [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/distccd-x86_64).

Alternatively, you can also try Clang/LLVM, which is available in Termux. It eliminates the need of building a cross-compilation toolchain, since Clang is inherently a cross compiler.

Comment: A cross-toolchain implies having headers that work for the target, and being able to actually link a binary executable against appropriate shared libraries for the target platform.  `clang -target x86_64` would let you build C to machine code in a `.o` (if the headers work), but likely doesn't come with shared libs to link against.  (And I'm not sure LLVM even includes a cross-linker at all.)

Comment: @PeterCordes For LLVM, maybe LLD can be used? According to LLD homepage, it is always a cross-linker.

Comment: Oh interesting, I didn't know LLVM included a linker these days.  https://lld.llvm.org/.  Arch GNU/Linux packages it separately from the rest of the `llvm`, as `lld`.  It wouldn't include libraries for ARM or other targets, but you could at least link static executables.

Comment: OP is talking about Android ARM, not Linux ARM.